# Restart the current operation of a while loop when an error is detected

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a PHP loop below which works fine however sometimes there will be a error page returned by the CURL request, how can I restart the operation for that current page only without restarting the whole loop?

```
while ($daytofetch <= $lastdaytofetch) {

//Do all my stuff and run curl request here 

$daytofetch++

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ($daytofetch <= $lastdaytofetch) {

    // Do all my stuff and run curl request here

    if ($error_detected) {
        // This will resume the loop without incrementing
        // $daystofetch
        continue;
    }

    $daytofetch++
}
```

Comment: So can you confirm that 'continue;' will restart the loop on the $daytofetch that it started on?

Comment: Using `continue` will return to the beginning of the `while` loop without changing any values that you don't want changed.  So in this case, after the `continue` statement is executed, `$daytofetch` will have the same value it had when this particular iteration of the `while` loop began.

Comment: Okay thanks, would I also be right in saying the `break` command will exit out and stop the loop?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do something like this:

```
while ($daytofetch <= $lastdaytofetch) {
    $error = false;


    //Do all my stuff and run curl request here
    //if there is an error, then set $error = true;


    if (!$error)
        $daytofetch++
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that by doing so you can get an infinite loop if the page always gives an error + you sent lots of requests to that server. Maybe you can count the errors, and stop retrying after 3 errors or so.